# How can I see how much data was transferred out of and into sql server during a given time period?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I see how much data was transferred out of and into sql server during a given time period?
I have an app that makes several SQL queries and updates during a run.  How can I see how much data was transferred into SQL Server and out of SQL Server during the time that this app was running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could achieve this (depending on your setup).

1. You could use a tool similar to Wireshark to monitor the traffic on the SQL Server port.  This would monitor, and even log, traffic in/out on that port.
2. Set up a Trace within SQL Server.  The Microsoft documentation site has a lot of material on setting up Traces. This is used by the SQL Profiler tool.
3. If you are with a host like AWS, you can report on that directly within the AWS console.  Whoever you are hosting with, if there isn't an obvious option to monitor this, you could still reach out to them and see if they have anything available. [This answer is only valid if you're using a host and not running a server from your house/office]